# How to get a list of all Choice field options using Client Object Model

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

How would you get a list of all the possible choices from a choice field (e.g. Task list Priority or Status fields) using javascript client object model?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can get this from [SP.FieldChoice.get_choices()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee553734.aspx) (SPFieldChoice inherits SPFieldMultiChoice)

To get that object you need to use [context.castTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658922.aspx) to cast SP.Field to SP.FieldChoice.

```
// Setup context and load current web
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
context.load();

// Get task list
var taskList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Tasks");

// Get Priority field (choice field)
var priorityField = context.castTo(taskList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Priority"),
                                   SP.FieldChoice);

// Load the field
context.load(priorityField);

// Call server
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),
                          Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));  

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
    // Get string arry of possible choices (but NOT fill-in choices)
    var choices = priorityField.get_choices();
    alert("Choices: (" + choices.length + ") - " + choices.join(", "));
}

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
    alert("oh oh!");
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know about context.castTo, this is brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: The above code needs to have a `context.load(priorityField);` before the `executeQueryAsync`! Otherwise you will get a property error when doing the `get_choices()`

Comment: You're right user16654, the code need to be used `context.load(priorityField);` before `executeQueryAsync`

Answer (score 3):

On SharePoint 2013, we can use the REST API. An example would be with a GET request similar to this:

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('task')/Fields?$filter=Title eq 'Fieldname'`

The request returns the field metadata. For more detail, view this link:

http://www.ozkary.com/2015/10/sharepoint-choice-field-options-with-angularjs.html?m=1

Comment: I can't get this to work with an App Web. Says permission denied with Admin creds

Comment: Keep in mind that calls to the SP API need to run under the security context of the user. You should login to SP. Open another tab (same browser) and enter the url with the apo call to test the access. The tabs should maintain the same security context. Double check that an Authorization header is send to the server with an auth token (dev tools)