# The property or Field not initialized exception even I request explicitly

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I'm using the following code to get the user permissions on a list item in javascript csom

```
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
              var field = context.castTo(searchtaxonomy_context.get_web().get_availableFields().getByTitle('Business Plan Year'), SP.FieldChoice);
context.load(field,'Choices');
context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                  var businessplanyearchoices = field.get_choices();},function(s,a){alert(a.get_message())});
```

I'm getting `'The property or field 'Choices' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested. '` in browser console.
I'm getting this same error when I load EfffectiveBasePermissions on a list item

Comment: This occurred because I've used the script tags directly to load sp.js. I removed the script references and used SharePoint on demand script loading by SP.SOD.executeFunc and it worked. The script reference was added in my SharePoint search control template.

Answer (score 2):

When getting field by title, it doesn't work. You should get it byInternalNameOrTitle. The reason is, it's SharePoint! This is why it is so hated and this is why it is so loved :)

This code piece worked for me (while if I replaced getByInternalNameOrTitle to getByTitle - I get the same error as you do):

```
var context=SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var field = context.get_web().get_availableFields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Priority");
var fieldChoice = context.castTo(field, SP.FieldChoice);
context.load(fieldChoice);
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  var choices = fieldChoice.get_choices();
  console.log(choices);
},
function(s,a){
  alert('ERR: ' + a.get_message());
});
```

[image]

Also, this question is sort of duplicate of this one:

- [How to get a list of all Choice field options using Client Object Model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21845/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-choice-field-options-using-client-object-model)

So don't forget to upvote Ryan's answer ;)

Though I think it doesn't hurt to emphasize that getByTitle doesn't work in this case.