# Change SharePoint 2010 Library field values at the time of Approval

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, column

[image]How to changes SharePoint 2010 library form values at the time of Approval, I have one UnderReview library, While Uploading the document there is one status column and the column values in Draft, Once the document Upload into the document library, the email goes to Administrator for Approval, when he will click the Approval Link then the UnderReview form will open and In the status column i need to show Approval,Progress and Expire field, Please help me to solve this issue, i will be very thankful to you all.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard SharePoint list (for example in a task list) the status column is of type choice. Via the list settings you can edit the different values which should be available for this column as choices.

In your case i would add all required values as choices (Draft, Approval, Progress and Expired).

If you don't want to have all choices available during the initial document upload you can use javascript to hide certain choices in your updload form.

Comment: Hi Please explain me the way to apply , how to apply java script code and where along with code,  Thanks !

Comment: Have a look at the SPFieldChoice class here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldChoice.aspx).
Example how to use it with Client Object Model here [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21845/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-choice-field-options-using-client-object-model)